# Call to a member function storeUploadedImage() on a non-object

Tags: php

As the title suggests in getting a fatal php error. The full error is

> Notice: Undefined variable: article in "location" on line 95
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function storeUploadedImage() on a non-object in "location" on line 95

The function where is error is being thrown is below

```
public function storeUploadedImage( $image ) {

  if ( $image['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
  {
    // Does the Article object have an ID?
    // Line 95 -----v
    if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Attempt to upload an image for an Article object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

    // Delete any previous image(s) for this article
    $this->deleteImages();

    // Get and store the image filename extension
    $this->imageExtension = strtolower( strrchr( $image['name'], '.' ) );

    // Store the image

    $tempFilename = trim( $image['tmp_name'] ); 

    if ( is_uploaded_file ( $tempFilename ) ) {
      if ( !( move_uploaded_file( $tempFilename, $this->getImagePath() ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
      if ( !( chmod( $this->getImagePath(), 0666 ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't set permissions on uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
    }
```

I have trawled through Google looking for a solution to my error although nothing appears relevant to my problem.

The rest of the post is created just not the image. when i got back to update the image uploads no problem with no errors which makes this puzzling.

The part of the class construct for id is

```
public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
  if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
```

I also use this to define id at the beginning of the class

```
public $id = null;
```

I can only assume the Id is not being passed correctly to `$this->id` and is remaining null but I have no idea of how to fix this. Although I am likely wrong about this too.

The method is called here

```
if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

// User has posted the articles edit form: save the new articles
$articles = new Article;
$articles->storeFormValues( $_POST );
$articles->insert();
if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image'] );
header( "Location: admin.php?status=changesSaved" );

} elseif ( isset( $_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
```

Comment: Where is your actual call to `storeUploadedImage()`? You've shown the method itself but not the call - that's there the problem is.

Comment: good point. I have just added the method where it is called

Comment: if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) $article **s** ->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image'] );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is called `$articles` not `$article`, change to:

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) $articles->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image'] );
                                     //  ^ note: s
```

Comment: This is definitely the problem, I suspect you aren't uploading/overwriting the file properly.

Comment: yeah you were right. the file didnt upload properly when i tested it and ran it again. tried again and it fixed it "_facepalm_" it's always something so simple. thank you for your help